# how sum multi different tables from mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 query

```
select uid, sum(call_duration) as cTime from privacy_call_history 
where event_date >= '2015-11-20 01:00:00' and event_date < '2015-11-20 01:00:00' + interval 1 hour
group by uid having sum(call_duration) > 0;

select uid, sum(run_time) as rTime from app_finish_history
where event_date >= '2015-11-20 01:00:00' and event_date < '2015-11-20 01:00:00' + interval 1 hour
group by uid having sum(run_time) > 0;

select uid, sum(chat_time) as wcTime, sum(msg_avg_time) as maTime from whisper_chat_history
where event_date >= '2015-11-20 01:00:00' and event_date < '2015-11-20 01:00:00' + interval 1 hour
group by uid having sum(chat_time) > 0 and sum(msg_avg_time) > 0;
```

I would like to combine them into a single resultset as demonstrated below:

```html
uid      cTime        rTime       wcTime             maTime
1  2   0   0   0
2  0   3   0   0
3  0   0   4   0
4  0   0   0   5
```

how can i make query?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the queries as subqueries into a single resultset. However, you will either need the user table from which the complete list of uids come from, or you need to simulate a full outer join in mysql. I would use the user table (or whatever it is called).

```
select user.uid, ifnull(t1.cTime,0) cTime, ifnull(t2.rTime,0) rTime, ifnull(t3.wcTime,0) wcTime, ifnull(t3.maTime,0) maTime
from user left join
(select uid, sum(call_duration) as cTime from privacy_call_history 
where event_date >= '2015-11-20 01:00:00' and event_date < '2015-11-20 01:00:00' + interval 1 hour
group by uid having sum(call_duration) > 0) t1 on user.uid=t1.uid
left join
(select uid, sum(run_time) as rTime from app_finish_history
where event_date >= '2015-11-20 01:00:00' and event_date < '2015-11-20 01:00:00' + interval 1 hour
group by uid having sum(run_time) > 0) t2 on user.uid=t2.uid
left join
(select uid, sum(chat_time) as wcTime, sum(msg_avg_time) as maTime from whisper_chat_history
where event_date >= '2015-11-20 01:00:00' and event_date < '2015-11-20 01:00:00' + interval 1 hour
group by uid having sum(chat_time) > 0 and sum(msg_avg_time) > 0) t3 on user.uid=t3.uid
```

If you want to filter out those users, who do not appear in any of the subselects, then add a where citeria requiring at least 1 not null value: coalesce(cTime, rTime, wcTime, maTime) is not null

Comment: Perhaps you could put a tick next to my answer then :)